# How to convert c# class to sql query adhoc?

Tags: c#, linq, serialization, ado.net

I have some class in C#:

```
class Person 
{
    string name;
    string lastname;
    int age;
}
```

I want to convert to SQL query with **detect types** for string and numbers (and so on).

For example: this class should convert to a SQL query like this:

```
insert into Person (name, lastname, age) 
values ('testname', 'testlastname', 42)
```

Beware that the values for string wrap with single-quote and integer are not.

There is a library somewhere that do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issue you are facing with that? You can start with reading about reflection in .net

Comment: I can only using ADO.NET with adhoc queries. this is my limitation. and I want to insert the class as is. instead of writing sql insert with string.format for each class. The question is can I do it without using reflection? ado.net params require to know what type is in db and what type you send to it.

Comment: You mean an ORM like Entity Framework?

Comment: creating sql statements like these is a security hazard as it's an open door for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: You should explore entity framework or nhibernate or dapper for this. Easy to use and plenty of examples available online

Comment: You are talking about (re)creating an ORM (object relationaldb mapper). There are already plenty of good ORMs available off the shelf for free, use those.

Comment: Yes. of course I know the disadvantage to use this way. but those are my limitation on the organization that I'm working in.  like I say I ONLY CAN USE ADO.NET ADHOC QUERIES.

Comment: If they have such a rule tell them it is ridiculous. I would fight that before I start to make my own ORM, it would probably take less time. Why not just ban using any 3rd party library and the .net framework while they are at it.

Comment: As far as the question is concerned it is too broad. If you must go this route, which I and strongly do not recommend, then you are on your own (*as far as [so] is concerned*) until you encounter a specific problem at which point you can post a question about that issue. However, a general question about how to build an orm is off topic.

Comment: Can you use parameters at all? I mean, can you create a query like this? `insert into Person (name, lastname, age) values (@name, @lastname, @age)`?